# Error in displaying two date-picker in one page html file

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using this widget http://www.frequency-decoder.com/2006/10/02/unobtrusive-date-picker-widgit-update

So, I use it on how it is supposed to be:

```
 <input type="text" class="w8em format-d-m-y divider-dash highlight-days-12
 range-low-today" id="dp-1" name="dp-1" value="" maxlength="10" style="width:
 120px;"/>
```

It is working, however I need two date-picker in one .html file. But the second file doesn't work. Nothing appears on the second `input`

Can I only use this once in one file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You surely can have a second date-picker. Give it a different `id` and `name` and it'll work. The following should give you two date-picker's with different id's (dp-1 and dp-2). I have tested this and it works for me...

```
<input type="text" class="w8em format-d-m-y divider-dash highlight-days-12
 range-low-today" id="dp-1" name="dp-1" value="" maxlength="10" style="width:
 120px;"/>
<input type="text" class="w8em format-d-m-y divider-dash highlight-days-12
 range-low-today" id="dp-2" name="dp-2" value="" maxlength="10" style="width:
 120px;"/>
```

Please see the following demo...

http://www.frequency-decoder.com/demo/date-picker-v2/reservation.html